# System.Device.dll is missing on mono

Tags: .net, mono

Does anyone know why System.Device.dll is missing on mono or where to find it?

According to the [status](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Device) it is implemented, but I cannot find it in neither

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/4.6.2-api

nor any other directories.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class That page should not be understood the way you did. Nope, this namespace is not implemented at all.

Comment: Seems you are correct. Though the legend "Items colored in green are complete" is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed switching to [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Device.Location.Portable/) package