# System.Device not found in Visual 2019 Mac

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am using System.Device.Location in .Net.

It works well in my Windows system but when I use the same code in my MacBook version of visual studio, it's not compiling:

> The type or namespace name 'Device' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234)

Here is my code:

```
using Toonbank.Vendor.Entity.DashBoard;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Device.Location;

namespace Toonbank.Vendor.Bal
{
    public class CalculateDistance
    {
        public double CalculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(CalculateDistanceClass obj)
        {
            //double latA = -31.997976f;
            // double longA = 115.762877f;
            //  double latB = -31.99212f;
            // double longB = 115.763228f;

            var locA = new GeoCoordinate(obj.lat1, obj.lon1);
            var locB = new GeoCoordinate(obj.lat2, obj.lon2);
            double distance = locA.GetDistanceTo(locB); // me
            double distanceToKm = distance / 1000;
            return distanceToKm;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: right click references and add a reference to System.Device?

Comment: System.Device is not available in the reference to add. I have attaached a screenshot of it as well. @Mikael

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536217/system-device-dll-is-missing-on-mono

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried that actually, but its apparently not the same thing

GeoCoordinateWatcher classes are missing so even if I add this reference,its shows and error when I try to use GeoCoordinateWatcher class

Comment: @JerinCherian I believe those things must reference Windows APIs and aren’t part of mono

Comment: @DanielA.White oh okay. would you happen to know any work around for this?

Comment: @JerinCherian what type of app are you writing?

Comment: @DanielA.White its an mvc website. It works fine in windows. I was going to debug it in safari. thats why i had to try using it in a mac

Comment: @JerinCherian I would open up ports in a windows machine and debug it that way

Comment: Thanks for asking this, having exact the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

`System.Device` is not an installed package built into the framework, it's a public package on Nuget you can reference at will. This is important because different systems have a different "device" inputs and outputs, like GPIO on a Raspberry Pi.

You seem to want the [`System.Device.Location.Portable`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Device.Location.Portable/) package.

Comment: I tried that actually, but its apparently not the same thing GeoCoordinateWatcher classes are missing so even if I add this reference,its shows and error when I try to use GeoCoordinateWatcher class @Blindy

Comment: `GeoCoordinateWatcher` is a Windows COM object, and it's obsolete since Windows 8 (we're at Windows 10 now). There is a replacement package for Windows that uses the new `Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator` class, but again that's Windows. If you want it under a Mac OS, you'll have to PInvoke some system calls to figure it out.